# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed in cv::Mat::Mat at line 269

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I paste a cuda code from Internet and run them but when executing erode and dilate function, the console window outputs error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in cv::Mat::Mat, file 
C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-
shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, 
line 269
```

if I delete erode and dilate function, they can work.
The erode and dilate function that produces error message is opencv built-in function not erodeInCuda or dilateInCuda. I have commented them in the code below.

Here's the code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


__global__ void erodeInCuda(unsigned char *dataIn, unsigned char *dataOut, Size erodeElement, int imgWidth, int imgHeight)
{

    int xIndex = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int yIndex = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    int elementWidth = erodeElement.width;
    int elementHeight = erodeElement.height;
    int halfEW = elementWidth / 2;
    int halfEH = elementHeight / 2;

    dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex] = dataIn[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex];

    if (xIndex > halfEW && xIndex < imgWidth - halfEW && yIndex > halfEH && yIndex < imgHeight - halfEH)
    {
        for (int i = -halfEH; i < halfEH + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -halfEW; j < halfEW + 1; j++)
            {
                if (dataIn[(i + yIndex) * imgWidth + xIndex + j] < dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex])
                {
                    dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex] = dataIn[(i + yIndex) * imgWidth + xIndex + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


__global__ void dilateInCuda(unsigned char *dataIn, unsigned char *dataOut, Size dilateElement, int imgWidth, int imgHeight)
{

    int xIndex = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int yIndex = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    int elementWidth = dilateElement.width;
    int elementHeight = dilateElement.height;
    int halfEW = elementWidth / 2;
    int halfEH = elementHeight / 2;

    dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex] = dataIn[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex];

    if (xIndex > halfEW && xIndex < imgWidth - halfEW && yIndex > halfEH && yIndex < imgHeight - halfEH)
    {
        for (int i = -halfEH; i < halfEH + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -halfEW; j < halfEW + 1; j++)
            {
                if (dataIn[(i + yIndex) * imgWidth + xIndex + j] > dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex])
                {
                    dataOut[yIndex * imgWidth + xIndex] = dataIn[(i + yIndex) * imgWidth + xIndex + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    Mat srcImg = imread("1.jpg");
    Mat grayImg = imread("1.jpg", 0);

    unsigned char *d_in;
    unsigned char *d_out1;
    unsigned char *d_out2;

    int imgWidth = grayImg.cols;
    int imgHeight = grayImg.rows;

    Mat dstImg1(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    Mat dstImg2(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out1, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out2, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char));

    cudaMemcpy(d_in, grayImg.data, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 32);

    dim3 blocksPerGrid((imgWidth + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x, (imgHeight + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y);

    Size Element(3, 5);

    erodeInCuda << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> >(d_in, d_out1, Element, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    cudaMemcpy(dstImg1.data, d_out1, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    Mat erodeImg;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 5));

    // error happens here
    erode(grayImg, erodeImg, element);

    dilateInCuda << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> >(d_in, d_out2, Element, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    cudaMemcpy(dstImg2.data, d_out2, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    Mat dilateImg;

    // error happens here.
    dilate(grayImg, dilateImg, element); 

    return 0;
}
```

so what's the problem? I see the example given by opencv official website and find nothing wrong. IDE is visual studio 2015 and opencv version is 2.4.13.

Comment: Is this some kind of an excercise? If not, why not upgrade to a more recent version and use [`cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d66/group__cudafilters.html#ga750f132b21ca48457c3e2e935d3bab27)

Comment: Yeah, I am learning how to use cuda. And I want to know why erode and dilate don't work because someday I will probably have to use them in cpu-only condition.

Comment: Alright, I found the reason. The project have read the wrong unmatched picture.